# What kind of Wraith would Frodo have become?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, nazgul

When Frodo is stabbed by the Witch King of Angmar's Morgul blade at Weathertop, Aragorn explains that Frodo is slowly becoming a wraith himself, the longer he goes untreated. If Frodo had become a wraith, would he have become one of the Nazgûl -- a ring wraith -- or would he have just been in a state of existence where he was neither living nor dead, but without a specific purpose (For example, hunting down the One Ring.), to just wander aimlessly?

**If his Morgul blade wound had not been healed, what kind of wraith would Frodo have become?**

Comment: A perpertually hungry one, with a bad nicotine habit, being a hobbit.

Comment: A rather small one, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Gandalf has this to say in the beginning of Book 2 of the Fellowship of the Ring, when he sits by the convalescent Frodo in Rivendell:

> If they had succeeded, you would have become like they are, only weaker and under their command. You would have became a wraith under the dominion of the Dark Lord; and he would have tormented you for trying to keep his Ring, if any greater torment were possible than being robbed of it and seeing it on his hand.

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting passage. I wonder if Frodo, as a wraith, would've been compelled to keep the One Ring for himself, or if he would've been compelled to take it to Sauron. Like, the Nine? Do they hunt the One Ring for themselves or for Sauron? (And, darn, I should've remembered what Gandalf said to Frodo about becoming a wraith -- I've read *Fellowship of the Ring*!)

Comment: the Nine have no will of their own, their only purpose is to serve the One and its master, Sauron (remember the ring bearer is not the master of the One, even if he may master its use to the degree his brain can manage).